# Insert node at beginning of linked list without using Node**

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am trying to add a new node at the beginning of an existing linked list that I created manually as I am still trying to learn about linked lists. I know you can use Node** to be able to do this but is there a way to do it only passing Node* to the function.

```
Node* insert( Node* head, int newval)
{
     Node* newnode = new Node;
     newnode->data = newval;
     newnode->next = head;
   
     head = newnode;

    return head;

}

int main()
{
    Node* head = new Node;
    Node* two = new Node;
    Node* three = new Node;

    head->data = 1;
    head->next = two;
    two->data = 2;
    two->next = three;
    three->data = 3;
    three->next = NULL;

    insert(head, 4);
```

I am getting: 123 instead of 4123.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What about `head = insert(head, 4);`? You `return head`, thus you can make use of it, can't you?

Comment: Btw. `three->next = NULL;` looks like an unlucky attempt to fix something. The `Node` should initialize `next` internally with a null pointer. Btw.² `NULL` is common in C but C++ has something better: `nullptr` which should be preferred.